# How to make a bootabe pendrive (USB Drive) consisting of multiple os?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb, dual-boot, bootable

Say I want to make a USB Drive that contains a bootable Ubuntu, Arch and other. How to do that?

Comment: For the most part the live /installer ISOs are capable of being loop mounted therefor you can use GRUB and just run each as an ISO file.

Comment: The other options is to use GPT partitions. You can have hundreds of them if you want. But its a little harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the strong things around Arch is that it has really good wiki. Most of the questions like this are already answered there and your one is also answered in good details here (for different options of usb drive creation - select whatever is better for you):

[Multiboot USB drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive)